# No ads found by MoPub while using the testing ad unit ID

Tags: android, ads, mopub

I'm embedding MoPub ads in my app. But it always returns "No Adds found" message. Though I'm using the testing ad unit ID "24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e" found [here](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/test/). It's for an Interstitial ad. What could be the reason?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle aSavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(aSavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);


    final HomeActivity mHomeActivity = this;

    SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e")
            .withLogLevel(MoPubLog.LogLevel.DEBUG)
            //.withLegitimateInterestAllowed(false)
            //.withAdditionalNetwork(InMobiAdapterConfiguration.class.getName())
            .build();

    MoPub.initializeSdk(this, sdkConfiguration, new SdkInitializationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFinished() {
            Log.d("Mopub", "SDK initialized");
            mInterstitial = new MoPubInterstitial(mHomeActivity, "24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e");
            mInterstitial.setInterstitialAdListener(mHomeActivity);
            mInterstitial.load();
        }
    });
}


public void onInterstitialLoaded(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {
    if (mInterstitial.isReady()) {
        mInterstitial.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInterstitialFailed(MoPubInterstitial interstitial, MoPubErrorCode errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MoPub failed: " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 83
        versionName "9.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'


    implementation ('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:5.15.0'){
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:mopub:5.3.0.1'

}
```

**Logcat - Filtered using the word "mopub" in "verbose" mode.**

```
2021-02-22 16:58:57.848 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.MoPub][initializeSdk] SDK initialization started
2021-02-22 16:58:57.849 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.MoPub][initializeSdk] SDK Log - SDK initialize has been called with ad unit: 24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e
2021-02-22 16:58:57.850 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.MoPub][initializeSdk] SDK Log - com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher was built with target SDK version of 29
2021-02-22 16:58:58.199 30005-30113/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.GpsHelper][fetchAdvertisingInfoSync] SDK Log - Unable to obtain Google AdvertisingIdClient.Info via reflection.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.200 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.TapjoyAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.TapjoyAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.202 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.ChartboostAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.ChartboostAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.204 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.FacebookAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.FacebookAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.205 30005-30113/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.privacy.PersonalInfoManager$5][onInitializationFinished] Consent Log - MoPubIdentifier initialized.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.205 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.IronSourceAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.IronSourceAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.207 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.SnapAdAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.SnapAdAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.209 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.VerizonAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.VerizonAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.211 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.AdColonyAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.AdColonyAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.213 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.AppLovinAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.AppLovinAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.214 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.217 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.VungleAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.VungleAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.218 30005-30106/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.util.AsyncTasks][safeExecuteOnExecutor] SDK Log - Posting AsyncTask to main thread for execution.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.219 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.PangleAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.PangleAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.220 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.AdapterConfigurationManager$AdapterConfigurationsInitializationAsyncTask][doInBackground] SDK Log With Throwable - Unable to find class com.mopub.mobileads.UnityAdsAdapterConfiguration, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mopub.mobileads.UnityAdsAdapterConfiguration
2021-02-22 16:58:58.270 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.GpsHelper][fetchAdvertisingInfoSync] SDK Log - Unable to obtain Google AdvertisingIdClient.Info via reflection.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.283 30005-30106/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.util.AsyncTasks][safeExecuteOnExecutor] SDK Log - Posting AsyncTask to main thread for execution.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.396 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.MoPub$InternalSdkInitializationListener][onInitializationFinished] SDK initialized and ready to display ads.
    Initialized adapters:
    No adapters initialized.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.399 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.GpsHelper][fetchAdvertisingInfoSync] SDK Log - Unable to obtain Google AdvertisingIdClient.Info via reflection.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.427 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher D/Mopub: SDK initialized
2021-02-22 16:58:58.445 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial][load] Ad attempting to load
2021-02-22 16:58:58.466 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController][loadNonJavascript] SDK Log - Loading url: https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=6&id=24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e&nv=5.15.0&dn=samsung%2CSM-M115F%2Cm11qnnxx&bundle=com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher&z=%2B0200&o=p&cw=720&ch=1495&w=720&h=1560&sc=1.75&mcc=602&mnc=03&cn=etisalat&ct=2&av=9.3&ifa=mp_tmpl_advertising_id&dnt=mp_tmpl_do_not_track&tas=mp_tmpl_tas&mid=mp_tmpl_mopub_id&gdpr_applies=0&force_gdpr_applies=0&current_consent_status=unknown&vv=4&vver=1.3.4-Mopub&mr=1
2021-02-22 16:58:58.474 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.GpsHelper][fetchAdvertisingInfoSync] SDK Log - Unable to obtain Google AdvertisingIdClient.Info via reflection.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.491 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.GpsHelper][fetchAdvertisingInfoSync] SDK Log - Unable to obtain Google AdvertisingIdClient.Info via reflection.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.506 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.AdLoader][fetchAd] Ad requesting from AdServer: https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad
    {"vv":"4","nv":"5.15.0","mid":"df2ad4d4-ab21-47e8-8d69-217e2cdfd024","dn":"samsung,SM-M115F,m11qnnxx","mcc":"602","sc":"1.75","current_consent_status":"unknown","vver":"1.3.4-Mopub","id":"24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e","bundle":"com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher","gdpr_applies":"0","mnc":"03","ch":"1495","ifa":"","mr":"1","tas":"authorized","h":"1560","force_gdpr_applies":"0","cn":"etisalat","dnt":"0","o":"p","ct":"2","cw":"720","av":"9.3","v":"6","w":"720","z":"+0200"}
2021-02-22 16:58:58.509 30005-30107/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.util.AsyncTasks][safeExecuteOnExecutor] SDK Log - Posting AsyncTask to main thread for execution.
2021-02-22 16:58:58.524 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.GpsHelper][fetchAdvertisingInfoSync] SDK Log - Unable to obtain Google AdvertisingIdClient.Info via reflection.
2021-02-22 16:58:59.290 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.TrackingRequest$1][onResponse] SDK Log - Successfully hit tracking endpoint: https://ads.mopub.com/m/open
2021-02-22 16:58:59.310 30005-30107/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.MultiAdResponse][parseSingleAdResponse] Ad server responded with:
    {"metadata":{"x-orientation":"p","x-scrollable":"0","x-adtype":"html","x-creativeid":"7f1de24619954d15b4b40eb4f75522f6","x-adgroupid":"365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97","vast-player-version":1,"content-type":"text\/html; charset=UTF-8","x-browser-agent":0,"imptrackers":["https:\/\/ads.mopub.com\/m\/imp?cid=7f1de24619954d15b4b40eb4f75522f6&city=Cairo&ckv=2&country_code=EG&cppck=60A51&current_consent_status=unknown&dev=SM-M115F&exclude_adgroups=365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97&gdpr_applies=0&id=24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e&is_mraid=0&os=Android&osv=10.0.0&priority=5&req=56b258b0fabf4c51b1555cabeb8e38b1_00d6e4c900bf13ef&reqt=1614005940.0&rev=0.000050&udid=mopub%3Adf2ad4d4-ab21-47e8-8d69-217e2cdfd024&video_type="],"impdata":{"id":"56b258b0fabf4c51b1555cabeb8e38b1_00d6e4c900bf13ef","adunit_id":"24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e","adunit_name":"Android Sample App Fullscreen","adunit_format":"Fullscreen","adgroup_id":"365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97","adgroup_name":"Non-Mrect Ads","adgroup_type":"gtee","currency":"USD","country":"EG","app_version":"9.3","adgroup_priority":6,"publisher_revenue":5.0E-5,"precision":"publisher_defined"},"x-after-load-url":"https:\/\/cb.mopub.com\/load?account_id=1308c11342c349e8a2934d8bb8fd33f6&adgroup_id=365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97&adgroup_priority=5&adgroup_type=gtee&adunit_format=Fullscreen&adunit_id=24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e&app_id=108e64891ab140adbe7d2325510533e9&campaign_id=ec34471d5f1443f79904715c075bdcbb&cid=7f1de24619954d15b4b40eb4f75522f6&cluster=atla&connection_type=2&country=EG&hostname=atla-ign-09-sr1.prod.twttr.net&is_mraid=0&log_attempt=1&logged_server_side=0&os=Android&request_id=56b258b0fabf4c51b1555cabeb8e38b1_00d6e4c900bf13ef&request_ts_ms=1614005940&round_trip_count=0&sdk_version=5.15.0&load_result=%%LOAD_RESULT%%&load_duration_ms=%%LOAD_DURATION_MS%%","clicktrackers":["https:\/\/ads.mopub.com\/m\/aclk?cid=7f1de24619954d15b4b40eb4f75522f6&city=Cairo&ckv=2&country_code=EG&cppck=D9E32&current_consent_status=unknown&dev=SM-M115F&exclude_adgroups=365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97&gdpr_applies=0&id=24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e&is_mraid=0&os=Android&osv=10.0.0&priority=5&req=56b258b0fabf4c51b1555cabeb8e38b1_00d6e4c900bf13ef&reqt=1614005940.0&rev=0&udid=mopub%3Adf2ad4d4-ab21-47e8-8d69-217e2cdfd024&video_type="],"x-before-load-url":"noop","x-ad-timeout-ms":30000},"content":"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>  <!-- Adgroup is 365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97 -->  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Security-Policy\" content=\"upgrade-insecure-requests\">  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">  <style type='text\/css'> .mp_center { position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -160px !important; margin-top: -240px !important; } <\/style>  <script type=\"text\/javascript\"> function mopubFinishLoad(){ setTimeout(function() { window.location = 'mopub:\/\/finishLoad'; }, 0); } <\/script>  <script type=\"text\/javascript\"> function webviewDidClose(){ if (typeof webviewDidCloseHelper == 'function') 
2021-02-22 16:58:59.311 30005-30107/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.MultiAdResponse][parseSingleAdResponse] { webviewDidCloseHelper(); } } function webviewDidAppear(){  if(typeof trackImpressionHelper == 'function') { trackImpressionHelper(); }  if(typeof webviewDidAppearHelper == 'function') { webviewDidAppearHelper(); } } window.addEventListener(\"load\", function() { var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++) { links[i].setAttribute('target','_blank'); } }, false); <\/script>  <\/head> <body style=\"margin:0;padding:0;\"> <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head><\/head>\n  <style>\n    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {\n      from { background-position: 0 0; }\n      to { background-position: 100% 0; }\n    }\n\n    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {\n      from { opacity: 0; max-width: 50%; }\n      to { opacity: 1; max-width: 100%; }\n    }\n\n  body, html {\n      padding: 0;\n      margin: 0;\n      font-family: \"HelveticaNeue-Light\", \"Helvetica Neue Light\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, \"Lucida Grande\", sans-serif;\n      height: 100%;\n    }\n\n    a {\n      color: black;\n      text-decoration: none;\n    }\n\n    footer,\n    header,\n    section {\n      display: block;\n    }\n\n    #workspace {\n      background-image: url(https:\/\/d30x8mtr3hjnzo.cloudfront.net\/creatives\/c45945f4063a4789a79aec907bcb04cc);\n      background-position: 0 0;\n      position: absolute;\n      top: 0;\n      bottom: 0;\n      left: 0;\n      right: 0;\n      width: 100%;\n      height: 100%;\n\n      -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;\n    }\n\n    header {\n      position: absolute;\n      top: 0;\n      left: 0;\n      right: 0;\n      height: 100px;\n      line-height: 100px;\n      background-color: #20ace5;\n      text-transform: capitalize;\n      color: white;\n      text-align: center;\n      font-size: 40px;\n    }\n\n    footer {\n      position: absolute;\n      bottom: 0;\n      left: 0;\n      right: 0;\n      text-align: center;\n      padding-bottom: 18px;\n    }\n\n    footer p {\n      font-size: 24px;\n      margin-bottom: 12px;\n      font-style: italic;\n      font-weight: 100;\n    }\n\n    .centered {\n      max-width: 100%;\n      height: auto;\n      overflow: auto;\n      margin: auto;\n      position: absolute;\n      top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;\n    }\n\n    #star-circle {\n    }\n\n    #nice {\n      -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;\n    }\n\n  <\/style>\n  <body> <a href=\"https:\/\/www.mopub.com\/click-test\/\">\n  <div id=\"workspace\">\n    <header>\n      Success!\n    <\/header>\n    <img id=\"star-circle\" class=\"centered\" src=\"https:\/\/d30x8mtr3hjnzo.cloudfront.net\/creatives\/e92584303dbf4f7e908f663060f3b07b\" \/>\n    <img id=\"nice\" class=\"centered\" src=\"https:\/\/d30x8mtr3hjnzo.cloudfront.net\/creatives\/6d4b7ded21fd41428ff2f0670ca3ba3f\"\/>\n    <footer>\n      <p>Tap to test this ad.<\/p>\n      <img id=\"mopub\" src=\"https:\/\/d30x8mtr3hjnzo.cloudfront.net\/creatives\/2a7466458cfd4c70adb556da05587270\">\n    <\/footer>\n  <\/div>\n  <\/a><\/body>\n<\/html> <script type=\"text\/javascript\"> i
2021-02-22 16:58:59.311 30005-30107/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.MultiAdResponse][parseSingleAdResponse] f (typeof htmlWillCallFinishLoad == \"undefined\" || !htmlWillCallFinishLoad) { if(typeof mopubFinishLoad == 'function') { window.onload = mopubFinishLoad; } }  <\/script>  <\/body> <\/html>"}
2021-02-22 16:58:59.331 30005-30108/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.util.AsyncTasks][safeExecuteOnExecutor] SDK Log - Posting AsyncTask to main thread for execution.
2021-02-22 16:58:59.331 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController][loadBaseAd] SDK Log - Loading ad adapter.
2021-02-22 16:58:59.334 30005-30108/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher E/Volley: [99861] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL noop
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL noop
        at com.mopub.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:143)
        at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
        at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
     Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: noop
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
        at com.mopub.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:87)
        at com.mopub.network.RequestQueueHttpStack.executeRequest(RequestQueueHttpStack.java:57)
        at com.mopub.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:91)
        at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132) 
        at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111) 
        at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90) 
2021-02-22 16:58:59.363 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController][loadBaseAd] SDK Error Log - Error loading ad adapter, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2021-02-22 16:58:59.366 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController][loadFailUrl] SDK Log With Throwable - Load failed., Unable to find Native Network or ad adapter.
2021-02-22 16:58:59.366 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController][loadNonJavascript] SDK Log - Loading url: 
2021-02-22 16:58:59.393 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.AdLoader][fetchAd] Ad requesting from AdServer: https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad
    {"vv":"4","nv":"5.15.0","mid":"df2ad4d4-ab21-47e8-8d69-217e2cdfd024","dn":"samsung,SM-M115F,m11qnnxx","mcc":"602","sc":"1.75","current_consent_status":"unknown","tqr":"YDPGtECd6NWetwCSAJVdtzT0KJJvAtddw2qd_g","exclude":"365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97","vver":"1.3.4-Mopub","id":"24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e","bundle":"com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher","gdpr_applies":"0","rtc":"1","ac":"0","mnc":"03","ch":"1495","ifa":"","mr":"1","tas":"authorized","force_gdpr_applies":"0","h":"1560","cn":"etisalat","dnt":"0","cppck":"D387D","o":"p","ct":"2","cw":"720","av":"9.3","v":"6","w":"720","z":"+0200","request_id":"56b258b0fabf4c51b1555cabeb8e38b1_00d6e4c900bf13ef"}
2021-02-22 16:58:59.395 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.TrackingRequest$1][onErrorResponse] SDK Log - Failed to hit tracking endpoint: noop
2021-02-22 16:58:59.396 30005-30114/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.common.GpsHelper][fetchAdvertisingInfoSync] SDK Log - Unable to obtain Google AdvertisingIdClient.Info via reflection.
2021-02-22 16:58:59.654 30005-30106/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.MultiAdResponse][parseSingleAdResponse] Ad server responded with:
    {"metadata":{"x-adtype":"clear","x-backfill":"clear","x-refreshtime":60},"content":""}
2021-02-22 16:58:59.656 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.AdLoader$1][onErrorResponse] Ad server responded with:
    No ads found for ad unit.
2021-02-22 16:58:59.658 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController][adDidFail] SDK Log - Ad failed to load.
2021-02-22 16:58:59.662 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial][onAdLoadFailed] Ad failed to load: (10,000) No ads found.
2021-02-22 16:59:00.269 30005-30005/com.mralshahawy.symbianbellelauncher I/MoPub: [com.mopub.network.TrackingRequest$1][onResponse] SDK Log - Successfully hit tracking endpoint: https://cb.mopub.com/load?account_id=1308c11342c349e8a2934d8bb8fd33f6&adgroup_id=365cd2475e074026b93da14103a36b97&adgroup_priority=5&adgroup_type=gtee&adunit_format=Fullscreen&adunit_id=24534e1901884e398f1253216226017e&app_id=108e64891ab140adbe7d2325510533e9&campaign_id=ec34471d5f1443f79904715c075bdcbb&cid=7f1de24619954d15b4b40eb4f75522f6&cluster=atla&connection_type=2&country=EG&hostname=atla-ign-09-sr1.prod.twttr.net&is_mraid=0&log_attempt=1&logged_server_side=0&os=Android&request_id=56b258b0fabf4c51b1555cabeb8e38b1_00d6e4c900bf13ef&request_ts_ms=1614005940&round_trip_count=0&sdk_version=5.15.0&load_result=missing_adapter&load_duration_ms=37
```

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine to me.
Do you have the detail device log showing the ad failed reason? Also, may I know if you are using landscape orientation in your layout?

If you have any other question, feel free to raise the issue in our [Github repositories](https://github.com/mopub).

Yoyo Lin
MoPub Team

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, really appreciated. I updated the question with the log. I'm testing it in portrait mode. My app supports both orientations screenOrientation="user"

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy Thanks for the detail information and debug log. Can you try to add the following dependencies below and see if it solves your problem?
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier and com.google.android.gms:play-services-base

Comment: For sorry it didn't. I even set minifyEnabled to false, and I got the same result.